# Automatic update with new data on ext.data.store

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, extjs

I have this extjs data store

```
    mystore= Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        id: 'store_id',
        fields: ['label', 'value', 'id', 'type'],
        autoLoad: true,
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: 'url/to/controller',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                root: 'MyModel'
            }
        }
    });
```

Is it possible with extjs configuration to make this store send ajax requests for new data on some interval (example 5 secs) automatically?

I want to use all functionality that extjs can provide so that I don't use php or additional javascript.

Comment: you could also look at server side push, such as websockets or comet

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [TaskManager](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.util.TaskManager) class to help with recurring tasks.

```
var task = {
    run: function() {
        mystore.load();
    },
    interval: 5000
}

// This will reload your store every 5 seconds
Ext.TaskManager.start(task);

// Call when you want to stop polling the server
Ext.TaskManager.stop(task);
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside of my grid code, i've put the function below and it worked:

```
setInterval(function() // IN YOUR CASE, IT RELOADS EACH 5 SECONDS
{
    storeReload = Ext.getStore("YourStoreHere");
    storeReload.load();
}
,5000);
```

I hope that have helped!!